# VBScript to dimsiss Excel warning dialog about external data sources?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have an Excel file that's linked to a SQL database view. The Excel file needs some monthly massaging that I am trying to do with a VBScript but this dialog box keeps coming up and interrupting my VBScript:

`This workbook contains links to one or more external sources that could be unsafe.`

`If you trust the links, update them to get the latest data. Otherwise, you can keep working with the data you have.`

And buttons for `Update`, `Don't Update` and `Help`

I do trust the data (it's our on-site SQL server), I don't want to refresh the data with this specific script (it takes about 15 minutes and it is refreshed via another process). But the dialog box is holding up my whole VBScript, how do I dismiss it? I've tried `ExcelObj.DisplayAlerts = False` and `ExcelObj.EnableEvents = False` but neither is making this dialog box go away. Please help!

Comment: Does [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ab786b4-45f7-4a48-b727-0903fd708a4c/im-getting-this-error-this-workbook-contains-links-to-one-or-more-external-sources-that-could-be?forum=excel) help?

Comment: Not exactly but from that link I found what I was looking for,